# Objects with different types of data and how to store and access them?

Tags: arrays, types, google-apps-script

I've worked with MATLAB before and storing and accessing multi-dimensional matrices or arrays were a breeze. But javascript/AppsScript is giving me a headache. I know that with GAS, one has to fake a 2D array with for loops and putting arrays in arrays.

At one time the form of `array[i][j]` works fine. Another time I can't access it at all.

I guess I need a quick summary of how arrays work in GAS. Especially multi-dimension array...

With that said, here is the specific scenario of why I need this answered.

I have something like this: (Purposefully left the second row with one data off. The rows do not necessarily have the same length.)

```
 A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
abc 456 789 012 345 678
def 234 567 890 123 
ghi 012 345 678 901 234
```

The first column has text and the rest are numbers. Basically, for reasons too long to say here, I need two arrays: One that is just the values from first column and one array that has the "array" of numbers from each row.

Something like this:

```
firstArray  = [abc, def, ghi];
secondArray = [[456, 789, 012, 345, 678], [234, 567, 890, 123], [012, 345, 678, 901, 234]];
```

Then to access them I have a double `for loop` setup:

```
for (var ii = 0; ii < firstArray.length; ii++) {
  do something with firstArray[ii];
  for (var jj = 0; jj < secondArray[ii].length) {
    do something with secondArray[ii][jj];
  }
}
```

To make the second array, I'm using the `getValues()`method. I do something like this:

```
sh.getRange('B1:1').getValues();
```

I have to do 'B1:1' since I can't seem to find a `lastColumn()` method for a `RANGE`. It is only there for `SHEET`. This leads to grabbing blank values for the `secondArray` when using the `getValues()`.

Anyways, I hope I didn't blab on too much. Any feedback is appreciated. I know this post is structured weirdly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I'm answering you're question here. I believe you want to go from this in a spreadsheet:

```
 A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
abc 456 789 012 345 678
def 234 567 890 123 
ghi 012 345 678 901 234
```

to this in Javascript arrays:

```
firstArray  = [abc, def, ghi];
secondArray = [[456, 789, 012, 345, 678], [234, 567, 890, 123], [012, 345, 678, 901, 234]];
```

It is best practice to use as few Google Apps Script spreadsheet API methods as possible. To that end I would get all the data with a single `getDataRange()` call:

```
var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
```

As you mentioned, `getValues()` will always return an array of arrays, where the outer array represents rows and the inner arrays are the cells in each row. So to extract into your new arrays:

```
var firstArray = [], secondArray = [];
for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
  firstArray.push(data[i][0]);
  secondArray[i] = [];
  for (var j = 1, width = data[0].length; j < width; j++) {
    if (!data[i][j]) break; //assumes no blank cells *within* the data
    secondArray[i].push(data[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Note the `map` Javascript method would probably provide a more concise way of doing this, but I'll leave that to someone more knowledgeable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I'd do it. Basically, read all of your sheet into one big 2D array and manipulate it from there.

```
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var colA = new Array(); 
var remainingCols = new Array(); 

for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
  colA.push(data[i][0]);
  remainingCols.push(data[i].slice(1));
}
```

[See here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) for a documentation of the slice() method. Using the slice() method, you can do it in a single loop.

Comment: This is awesome and is going to cut my time in half. I have bookmarked the documentation you linked to. I still chose AdamL's post the accepted answer, but only because it also addressed the variation in the `secondArray`'s arrays. I am going to use the `splice` method along with others from your link and AdamL's to finish my code. Thanks a bunch!